# TCP Windows scaling on Windows 2008 server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, tcp, scaling

If found only this article on windows 2008 server or Windows 7 TCP Windows scaling.

http://8help.osu.edu/3253.html

Is there any other information that I can use to change registry that would modify the TCP Window size?

Answer (score 1):

You can find some useful info here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb878127